# How to disambiguate P3P 4 solutions for Visual Odometry

Tags: computer-vision

I have implemented the P3p algorithm described in the following paper "A Novel Parametrization of the Perspective-Three_Point problem for Direct Computation of Absolute Camera Position and Orientation".

However the procedure provides 4 solutions, i.e., for combination of (translation, orientation). 
Now I am supposed to disambiguate the 4 solutions and get a unique solution by BACK PROJECTION OF A FOURTH POINT.

My understanding is that back projection means to take the fourth point and re-project it on the image plane. But how is that going to help me with finding a unique solution from the above 4?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

I might have an idea to what this means.
Basically you take a fourth world point and re-project it using all four rotations+translations. Then you choose the solution closest to the re-projection.